# Weird issue with NSMenu

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am showing NSMenu with below method. Mouse over events and actions on MenuItems are working fine.

```
if let event = NSApplication.shared.currentEvent          
 NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(menu, with: event, for: self.view)
}
```

Now, to have this menu at different position I changed this method to below and all the events like mouse over and selections are not working.

```
 menu.popUp(positioning: item1, at: position, in: self.view)
```

Please suggest me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where do you call this? On the main thread? Did you change something else?

Comment: Yes it is on main thread.